# How to make a graph on Python describing WordNet's synsets (NLTK)

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk, networkx, wordnet

I'm a totally noob here, so forgive me for my sins. Here's the problem: even though I only copy-pasted a code from a manual called "Natural Language Processing with Python", I can't find a way to make a graph fro the code I'll post down below. My "only" goal it's to show in my thesis how codes interact with graphs in WordNet. Here's the code:

```
# Natural Language Toolkit: code_networkx

import networkx as nx
import matplotlib
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn

def traverse(graph, start, node):
    graph.depth[node.name] = node.shortest_path_distance(start)
    for child in node.hyponyms():
        graph.add_edge(node.name, child.name) # [_add-edge]
        traverse(graph, start, child) # [_recursive-traversal]

def hyponym_graph(start):
    G = nx.Graph() # [_define-graph]
    G.depth = {}
    traverse(G, start, start)
    return G

def graph_draw(graph):
    nx.draw_graphviz(graph,
         node_size = [16 * graph.degree(n) for n in graph],
         node_color = [graph.depth[n] for n in graph],
         with_labels = False)
    matplotlib.pyplot.show()



>>> dog = wn.synset('dog.n.01')
>>> graph = hyponym_graph(dog)
>>> graph_draw(graph)
```

No errors popped up, but still, no graph here. Pardon me for the lenght of the message but I'm truly in your hands! :/

Comment: Hello, @denni95HM, don't forget to mark my question as correct (and upvote it) if it answers the question.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because you rely on graphviz. Here is an example use that works:

```
import networkx as nx 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

G = nx.petersen_graph()
nx.draw(G)
plt.show()
```

So you should do something like the following:

```
def graph_draw(graph):
    nx.draw_shell(graph)
    matplotlib.pyplot.show()
```

Link to the [official documentation](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/drawing.html#module-networkx.drawing.nx_pylab).